# Process JSON String Data with Spark Scala

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql

The below entire data present in single column. For Each ID we may have more than one Party
How to Convert this into an structured format.

{"123": {"Partyl": {"FIRSTNAMEBEN": "ABC","ALIASBEN": "","RELATIONSHIPTYPE": "ABC, FGHIJK LMN","DATEOFBIRTH": "7/Oct/1969"},"Party2": {"FIRSTNAMEBEN": "ABCC","ALIASBEN": "","RELATIONSHIPTYPE": "ABC, FGHIJK LMN","DATEOFBIRTH": "7/Oct/1969"}},"GeneratedTime": "2022-01-30 03:09:26"}

{"456": {"Partyl": {"FIRSTNAMEBEN": "ABCD","ALIASBEN": "","RELATIONSHIPTYPE": "ABC, FGHIJK LMN","DATEOFBIRTH": "7/Oct/1969"},"Party2": {"FIRSTNAMEBEN":"ABCDD","ALIASBEN":"","RELATIONSHIPTYPE": "ABC, FGHIJK LMN","DATEOFBIRTH": "7/Oct/1969"},"Party3": {"FIRSTNAMEBEN": "ABCDDE","ALIASBEN": "","RELATIONSHIPTYPE": "ABC, FGHIJK LMN","DATEOFBIRTH": "7/Oct/1969"}},"GeneratedTime": "2022-01-30 03:09:26"}

{"345": {},"GeneratedTime": "2022-01-30 03:09:26"}

Expected Output:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/76R5A.jpg)

**Sample Data:**

val values = List(List("123", """"{"123": {"Partyl": {"FIRSTNAMEBEN": "ABC","ALIASBEN": "","RELATIONSHIPTYPE": "ABC, FGHIJK LMN","DATEOFBIRTH": "7/Oct/1969"},"Party2": {"FIRSTNAMEBEN": "ABCC","ALIASBEN": "","RELATIONSHIPTYPE": "ABC, FGHIJK LMN","DATEOFBIRTH": "7/Oct/1969"}},"GeneratedTime": "2022-01-30 03:09:26"}"""") ,List("456", """"{"456": {"Partyl": {"FIRSTNAMEBEN": "ABCD","ALIASBEN": "","RELATIONSHIPTYPE": "ABC, FGHIJK LMN","DATEOFBIRTH": "7/Oct/1969"},"Party2": {"FIRSTNAMEBEN":"ABCDD","ALIASBEN":"","RELATIONSHIPTYPE": "ABC, FGHIJK LMN","DATEOFBIRTH": "7/Oct/1969"},"Party3": {"FIRSTNAMEBEN": "ABCDDE","ALIASBEN": "","RELATIONSHIPTYPE": "ABC, FGHIJK LMN","DATEOFBIRTH": "7/Oct/1969"}},"GeneratedTime": "2022-01-30 03:09:26"}"""") ,List("345", """"{"345": {},"GeneratedTime": "2022-01-30 03:09:26"}"""")).map(x =>(x(0), x(1)))

val df = values.toDF ("CaseID","RelatedParty")

df.show

Comment: please upload the valid json

Comment: I have updated now. Please check

Comment: @Kishore expected output is not in proper format? also add some code what you tried

Comment: How do you want the output in the case of the last record i.e `345`? Do you want to ignore it or else how do you need it?

Comment: @whatsinthename I am expecting like below for the record 345 
 345  Null  Null  Null    Null  2022-01-30 03:09:26

Comment: @Kishore I have had modified my solution. Note that, Null case is still pending. Will get back to you once I get time to figure that out. This is just a hack for your case.

Comment: Your last record format isn't correct. Is it generated like this? Because when I try to load your dataset, the last record is filtered out which is a corrupt record according to the parser. Can you place empty fields for that record?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below way to achieve what you want.

```
 val df = spark.read.option("multiline", true).json("...json")
 

 val df1 = df.
 select(explode(array("123.*")) as "level1").
  withColumn("ID",lit(df.columns(0))).
  withColumn("FIRSTNAMEBEN", col("level1.FIRSTNAMEBEN")).
  withColumn("ALIASBEN", col("level1.ALIASBEN")).
  withColumn("RELATIONSHIPTYPE", col("level1.RELATIONSHIPTYPE")).
  withColumn("DATEOFBIRTH", col("level1.DATEOFBIRTH")).
  drop("level1")
```

`Output`:

```
scala>  df1.show(false)
+---+------------+--------+----------------+-----------+
|ID |FIRSTNAMEBEN|ALIASBEN|RELATIONSHIPTYPE|DATEOFBIRTH|
+---+------------+--------+----------------+-----------+
|123|ABCC        |        |ABC, FGHIJK LMN |7/Oct/1969 |
|123|ABC         |        |ABC, FGHIJK LMN |7/Oct/1969 |
+---+------------+--------+----------------+-----------+
```

**`Update 1`**:

Based on the `modified` input, below is a kind of hack that works dynamically. However, it doesn't handle the `Null` case yet as I didn't get the bandwidth to figure out the solution for `Null` cases. It is also `NOT` an optimal solution since it writes to the disk for every flattened record, so higher `disk I/O`.

Meanwhile, you can go through the code:

```
val onlyDigitsList = df.columns.toList.filter(x => x.matches("^[0-9]*$"))
var colName=""


for(i<-onlyDigitsList.zipWithIndex)
{
println(i._2)
colName=i._1.toString()
println(colName)
val df1 = df.
 select(explode(array(s"$colName.*")) as "level1").
  withColumn("ID",lit(colName)).
  withColumn("FIRSTNAMEBEN", col("level1.FIRSTNAMEBEN")).
  withColumn("ALIASBEN", col("level1.ALIASBEN")).
  withColumn("RELATIONSHIPTYPE", col("level1.RELATIONSHIPTYPE")).
  withColumn("DATEOFBIRTH", col("level1.DATEOFBIRTH")).
  drop("level1")
  if(i._2==0)
{

df1.filter((!col("FIRSTNAMEBEN").isNull) &&(!col("ALIASBEN").isNull) && (!col("RELATIONSHIPTYPE").isNull) && (!col("DATEOFBIRTH").isNull)).write.mode("overwrite").json("/home/.../Documents/jsonData/")
}

if(i._2>0)
{
  df1.filter((!col("FIRSTNAMEBEN").isNull) &&(!col("ALIASBEN").isNull) && (!col("RELATIONSHIPTYPE").isNull) && (!col("DATEOFBIRTH").isNull)).write.mode("append").json("/home/.../Documents/jsonData/")
}
}
```

**`Assumption`**: The `ID` column will be numeric-only or else the regex will change.

If your input format changes, the code changes. There is no such `generic solution` for `JSON` datasets.

I will edit this answer once I figure out the `Null` case or even you can try it out and try to tweak this code and maybe you can come out with a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
schema=StructType([StructField('123',MapType(StringType(),StructType([
StructField('ALIASBEN',StringType(),True),StructField('DATEOFBIRTH',StringType(),True),StructField('FIRSTNAMEBEN',StringType(),True),StructField('RELATIONSHIPTYPE',StringType(),True),]),True))])


df =spark.read.json(path= '/content/sample_data/new.json',multiLine=True,schema=schema)

df.select(explode('123')).select('value.*').show()
```

Comment: Hi @Francis Joseph , I Can't use explode on column 123 , because I may have more than 1 lakh ID

Comment: Hi @Kishore I have worked on similar dataset with 50+ Gb in size.

Comment: Can you please help me on this

Comment: please attach the exact dataset

Comment: I have updated with sample data. Please check
But my data size is 80gb

Answer (score -2):

```
// Please note that if your json data is multiline the do add an option for multiline   

spark.read.option("multiline", true).json("/path/to/json/file")
     .selectExpr("stack(1,'123',`123`) as (ID,value)")
     .withColumn("Party1",col("value.Partyl"))
     .withColumn("Party2",col("value.Party2"))
     .selectExpr("ID","stack(2,'Party1',Party1,'Party2',Party2) as (key1,value1)")
     .select(col("ID"),col("value1.*")).show
    
// Here is the output of the above code.    

+---+--------+-----------+------------+----------------+
| ID|ALIASBEN|DATEOFBIRTH|FIRSTNAMEBEN|RELATIONSHIPTYPE|
+---+--------+-----------+------------+----------------+
|123|        | 7/Oct/1969|         ABC| ABC, FGHIJK LMN|
|123|        | 7/Oct/1969|        ABCC| ABC, FGHIJK LMN|
+---+--------+-----------+------------+----------------+
```

Comment: It's a good idea to explain a little your code rather than post it raw. Besides that, it's not necessary to create a RDD first. It's better to use DataFrames in this case.

Comment: @jocerfranquiz thank you for your suggestion. I will explain my answer in a better way. Here the point is not the creation of rdd. We could have read the json data from a file. What is important is the way json was parsed. Rdd was just a way to read json data.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).